# Tab throug input fields when display:none

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, tabindex

Imagine that:

```
<div>
    <input tabindex="1">
</div>
<div style="display:none">
    <input tabindex="2">
</div>
<div>
     <input tabindex="3">
</div>
```

Now I'm trying to tab through all these input fields, but he is not stepping into tabindex 2. Logical that this not working, but how i could implement that when he is on tabindex 1 and is supposed to go to tabindex 2 that the div becomes visible ?.

Thanks

Comment: Make it `opacity: 0` which would make the tabindex work I think. And then when you focus on the field you remove the `opacity`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, make your `div` have `opacity: 0`. When you focus on that input that is hidden, you make it `opacity: 1`. Something like:

```
<div>
    <input tabindex="1"/>
</div>
<div style="opacity: 0">
    <input tabindex="2"/>
</div>
<div>
    <input tabindex="3"/>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('div:eq(1) input').on('focus', function() {
    $(this).parent().css('opacity','1');
}).on('blur', function() {
    $(this).parent().css('opacity','0');
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/88p76e29/)

Or you could do something with `height` (`height: 0` / `height: auto`):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/88p76e29/1/)

But from a user experience point of view it would be strange to have an extra `input` popup where you don't expect it.

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with the advice given here and instead decided to use `left: -999px; position: absolute;` simply setting the left on hover or keyboard nav (using tabindex).

Just to say that basically `height:0` won't always work, and in those cases extreme `translate: transformX(-999)` or simpler `left: -999px` with `position: absolute` works just as well.